# How to remove the download button or copy button from the browser in pdf files?

Tags: html, pdf

How to remove save file button when we are seeing any pdf files in browser.
Is there any way to remove save button or make not down loadable? [ pdf file ]

Yes i know, user can select the file content then copy paste it,
But then also, there can be many user which will not know to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could integrate the PDF in a visor, some like a Flash Player. For example, the one used in http://www.slideshare.net/
They embedded the presentations (PPT, ODF, PDF,...) with a Flash Player, so the visitor can't download the document.

Answer (score 0):

1. Impossible; you can't modify the appearance of a plugin (e.g. Adobe Reader)
2. Users can grab the path anyway and `wget` it, even if you could.

Comment: I think...i have to take some different route to take care of my data.
Thanks for replay.

Answer (score 0):

Just add parameters after the url.Like www.xxx.com/a.pdf#toolbar=0.
Then browser will hide the toolbar.